# Unable to execute file in the temporary directory Error 2: The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: windows, git

I am trying to download GIT to a computer that does not have access to internet. In the process, I am getting this error message:

"Unable to execute file in the temporary directory Error 2: The system cannot find the file specified"

I have downloaded the installation file, Git-2.23.0-64-bit.exe, from Git website. I have then copied it to a shared drive. After that, I remotely connected to the computer (the one I want to download Git to) using VNC. I have copied the installation file to the Desktop of the remote computer. Then, when I double click on it to open it, I get this error message:

"Unable to execute file in the temporary directory Error 2: The system cannot find the file specified."

I know I do have administrators rights with the user I am working with. I have tried to log in with other users, administrators and not, but cannot get the file to open.

Comment: i think that you should remove all the tags but `windows`. It has nothing to do with git, vnc, ...

Comment: Removed unnecessary tags. Left Git because this issue is only happening with Git installation.